# How to apply business rules to object?

Tags: php, design-patterns, business-logic

What is the best way verify a user object with 2 different sets of business rules requirements? I am using a datamapper pattern to save my domain objects to the persistence layer.

Examples:
1. Client A requires only the name to be present for the user object to be valid and be allowed to be saved to the persistence layer.

1. Client B requires the name and at least one hobby to be present in the user object in order for it to be considered valid.
2. Client A decides at a later time that they require a telephone number for the user object to be valid.

Is there a good pattern for implementing these dynamic business rules on a domain object where the rules may change?

```
<?php

class User{

    private $_name;

    private $_telephone;

    private $_hobbies = array();

    public __construct(){

    }

    public function setName($strName){
        $this->_name = $strName;
    }

    //Other getter and setter.....

}

    class UserMapper{

        public __construct(){

        }

        public function save(user $objUser){
            //preform mapper save operations to persistence layer(db, file, etc)
        }

    }

    //instantiate the user mapper class
    $objUserMapper = new userMapper();

    //instantiate the user domain class
    $objUser = new User();
    $objUser->setName('John Hancock');

    //save the user to the persistence layer
    $objUser->save($objUser);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. Try a business rule engine like Ruler (http://jwage.com/post/31292541379/ruler-a-simple-stateless-production-rules-engine-for)